# Wrong output when I use placeholder

Tags: c#, .net, output, console.writeline

When I use the {0} placeholder in C#, I get the wrong output.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using static System.Console;
    namespace Ch06Ex03
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int argument = 10;//test argument
                WriteLine($"The argument is={argument}");
                *WriteLine($"The argument is={0}",argument);*/*Here,When I use the {0},output is 0,Why not is 10?*/
                ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because the `$` prefix means that `{0}` becomes `0`. Avoid using an interpolated string as a format specifier. If you need to, you have to escape the `{}` by doubling them.

Comment: This is a User Error, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error

Answer (score 6):

You're mixing an interpolated string and a composite format.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings for more information.

**Interpolated string**

```
Console.WriteLine($"Key: {value}");
```

$ signifies that we're using an interpolated string.

**Composite format**

```
Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}", value);
```

The composite format is only available in specific methods like `Console.WriteLine`, `String.Format`, ... In these methods the "0" signifies the index in the following arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The dollar sign before a string signals the compiler to perform interpolation, in a sense interpreting the sections between your brackets as code. Remove the dollar sign to perform regular format operations.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings

Answer (score 0):

First, remove this (which won't even compile on my VS2012:

```
using static System.Console;
```

Then, use this:

```
int argument = 10;//test argument
 Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The argument is={0}", argument));
 Console.ReadKey();
```

Generally it's better practice to qualify methods with a class. It makes the intent clear, and prevents ambiguous reference compile errors if two classes were to contain the same method name.

Answer (score 0):

This version works fine. The problem is the dollar symbol in the second case in your version.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace ConsoleApplication1
 {
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
        int argument = 10;//test argument
        Console.WriteLine($"The argument is={argument}");
        Console.WriteLine("The argument is={0}", argument);
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The argument is = {0}", argument));//Otra forma        
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}